# Is there any way to use UIColor(named: "") .colorset files in Playgrounds?

Tags: xcode, uicolor, swift-playground

I put some .colorset files in the resources folder of a Playground, and tried using `UIColor(named: "color name")!` but I just get an error about `'... found nil'` so it seems like it's just not going to work.

Is there any way to use Named UIColors in a Swift Playground?